# WSS 3.0 Authentication mode

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, vsewss

I have two questions on **wss 3.0**

1. How to know that kind of authentication is currently in use.
2. How do I set the authentication in such a way that users on office network don't have to input user name\password? So if users are in the office they can just go straight in without using a password? Those outside the office will obviously still have to use the password.

Detail answer would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

For #2, you also need to make sure that Internet Explorer has your site listed as a trusted site or intranet site so that IE will be willing to pass the credentials to the Sharepoint Server

Comment: Isn’t it like storing the password? i.e. if one clears the cache and offline files then he will have to input the user name and password. isn’t it? And what if they browse the site using different browsers? the have to provide password for all of them.

I think if we can configure the windows authentication in such a way that if the request comes from within the domain it will not require authentication otherwise it will ask for the username and password.

Comment: NTLM is used to send a token to the web server, but the web server and client must be in the same domain (or domains that trust each other). IE and Firefox can do NTLM.  When this is used, the user types in the password when they log onto the machine, but they do not give a password to the web browser, and it is not passed to the web server.  Rather, a token is retrieved from the domain controller (at time of login), and if the site is in trusted sites / intranet (IE), the token will be sent to the web server as authentication.  The idea with #2 is that you don't have to type in the password.

Answer (score 0):

There are two build-in authentication types: windows and forms.

1. You can configure it in central administration (as far as I remember in "Application Management" section).
2. Windows authentication will use current user's windows credentials to login on site. So if SharePoint is configured with windows authentication and permissions were granted to user there will be no request to enter login/password. In other case (outside of office for example) site will ask for credentials.

Comment: Option#2 sounds good. How do we set the permission in such a way?

Comment: Authentication provider does not affect permissions.